# Laplace transform notation

Tags: notation, laplace-transform

I'm confused about the notation used, pretty much everywhere, to describe what a Laplace transform it.

Wikipedia says something along the lines of "..Laplace transform of a function $f(t)$..", mathworld similarly has this definition

$\mathcal L_t[f(t)]=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$

What's strange to me is that $f(t)$ here is treated as a function instead of a number ($f$ is the actual function here).

This isn't unusual in mathematical texts and perhaps only a little bit annoying sometimes but I feel like in this case there's some special significance.

What's the explanation for this 'wrong' notation?

Comment: The problem is pretty common, unfortunately. It's even worse with the Hilbert transform, see King for example. It took me hours to decode some of his God awful notation in that text. Proper mathematical notation would be to write $\mathcal{L}(f)(s) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t)\,dt.$ As for an explanation.. I would think it's just because most non-math students don't know that there is a distinct difference between $f$ and $f(t)$, i.e. $f$ is the function and $f(t)$ is actually the *value* of $f$ at $t$. It's an unfortunate byproduct of our education system.

Comment: Or perhaps even more rigorous notation would be $[\mathcal{L}(f)](s) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}f(t)\,dt$, signifying that $\mathcal{L}(f)$ is a function, which we are evaluating at $s$.

Comment: More crappy notation, but it is ingrained. A better notation would be something like $({\cal L} f) (s)$, or even just a 'hat' ($\hat{f}$) to denote the transformed function.

Comment: Or even ${\cal L}(t \mapsto f(t))(s)$.

Comment: @copper.hat: But the difference between $\mathcal L_t[f(t)]$ and $\mathcal L(t\mapsto f(t))$ is just punctuation, right? No worse than integral or indexed-sum notations binding variables. I would be happy with $\mathcal L_t[f(t)]=(s\mapsto \int\cdots dt)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: It is, but since there are fairly standard existing and unambiguous notations in this case it would seem better to use them (from an educational perspective). (I don't mean to suggest that all potentially ambiguous convenience 'devices' are bad, just that they should be used judiciously and with extra care for the beginner.)

Comment: @CameronWilliams I actually prefer your $\mathcal{L}(f)(s)$ to $[\mathcal{L}f](s)$.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy I definitely prefer the former but I most prefer $\mathcal{L}f(s)$ and it's what I use in practice. Too many parentheses make it difficult to read complicated expressions sometimes.

Comment: I use $F(s)$ in practise!