# Why do we surround the argument of the Laplace transform operator with $\{$ and $\}$?

Tags: notation, laplace-transform

Is there a special reason why we write $\mathcal{L} \{ x\}$ instead of $\mathcal L (x)$? Do the curly brackets have some sort of special meaning (mathematical or notational/conventional)? I think the only other places I've seen curly brackets intentionally used is when denoting multisets, which I'm pretty sure is not relevant here

Comment: Interestingly, the Mellin transform ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform)) has a similar convention, though the Fourier transform ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)) doesn't often, even though all three are integral transforms (more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform)). Maybe it's tradition to some extent, but I don't know for sure. Interesting question.

Comment: Another few examples with a curly-brace notation seem to be Hartley ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_transform)), Hermite ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_transform)), Jacobi ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_transform)), Laguerre ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_transform)), and Legendre ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transform)). Not sure if it means anything though.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Very cool, thank you!! Interesting to see that they're all integral transforms

Comment: I think people tend to repeat the convention that they were taught. The convention I was exposed to initially used square brackets as in ${\cal L}[ f(t)]$, though personally I would prefer ${\cal L} f $ or ${\cal L} (t \mapsto f(t))$. Another popular convention, shared with the Fourier transform is $\hat{f}$.

Comment: @copper.hat As in $\hat{f} = \mathcal{L}\{ f \}$? If so that's surprising, but maybe not too surprising because I guess integral transforms don't come up in linalg settings where we'd see the hat on other things

Comment: Yes, I have seen the $\hat{f}$ notation in many places (Rudin, control system books).

Comment: I second copper.hat's comment. When I do personal calculations I parse $\mathcal L\{f(t)\}$ as $(\mathcal Lf)(s)$ (since people write things like $\mathcal L\{e^{at}\}=\frac 1 {s-a}$.
Similarly, when I see derivatives written in Leibniz notation I translate $\frac d{dx}x^2$ as $(t\mapsto t^2)'(x)$.
I think both are cases of an excessive emphasis on the dummy variables we use when defining functions, instead of the functions themselves.

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123865/laplace-transform-notation)

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I like this (t↦t2)′(x) notation! where can I find an explanation of it? Does it have a name?